# class in separate file c++

Tags: c++, file, class

Hello I'm working on CLR application in C++. After few hours of work I decided that moving classes to different files will be better idea than putting everything in the same file. I created new header file and new cpp file but I'm just a beginner so there's a chance I did something wrong.

this is my header file

```
#pragma once

class Show {
public:
    void Show::show_all(int num, int id_master, int id_slave, int periferia, int data);
};
```

my cpp file (just simple printing function)

```
#include "Show.h"
#include <stdio.h>

class Show{
private:
    void show_all(int num, int id_master, int id_slave, int periferia, int data) {

    printf("%d\n", num);
    printf("id of mastra is: %d\n", id_master);
    printf("id of slave is: %d\n", id_slave);
    printf("id of device is: %d\n", periferia);
    printf("in data part %d\n", data);

    };
};
```

then in main I'm doing something like this

```
Show sh;
```

and then, when I try calling my function like this

```
sh.vypis_vsetko(num, id_master, id_slave, periferia, data);
```

but i get many errors which I dont understand (all in main function)

- 'sp': undeclared identifier (always when I mention it)
- 'Show': undeclared identifier
- left of '.show_all' must have class/struct/union
- syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'sh'

I spent a lot of time trying to solve this but without any conclusion.
I will be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: There are a lot of really basic errors here. Please check out a tutorial about separating the header and implementation file.

Comment: Ok, the code is not correct at all, though I am curious, why would you want to change the access modifier from `public` to `private`?

Answer (score 4):

For starters, in the header file, declaring a class method is done without prefixing the class name to the method name:

```
class Show {
public:

     void show_all(int num, int id_master, int id_slave, int periferia, int data);
};
```

Finally, defining a class method in a `.cpp` file is done without the class declaration, whatsoever:

```
void Show::show_all(int num, int id_master, int id_slave, int periferia, int data) {

    printf("%d\n", num);

    // the rest of the code.
```

You already declared the class, in the `#include`d header file.

Comment: The full class declaration does need to be visible from the definition of its functions, but not as OP wrote it indeed.

Comment: The header file is getting `#include`d, so that should be fine.

Comment: I've tried to correct my code but I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, just picking on the "is done without the class declaration, whatsoever" bit ;)